# mailtrap: sending mail using mailtrap in laravel but it deliver in different mailtrap account

Tags: php, laravel, mailtrap

i am using mailtrap for my laravel project.am facing an issue like ,i already set an maitrap account in .env and mail.php file in laravel.but after sending mail,for example if there is 2 mail,one mail delivery in mail trap account which is specified in .env other one send to different mailtrap account.dono whats the pblm.here i am attaching my .env mailtrap details.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=774b7621a36786
MAIL_PASSWORD=b43de6b4f4e5b2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

anyone please help me.i already run cache/config clear.

Comment: I hope you `username` and `password` are not real (production) data? Never publish your real access data. The other thing is: You need to define your mail account either in `.env` or in your config. Furthermore the config file using your settings from the `.env` file. So you only need to define it in your `.env` file and keep the config originally as it comes with a fresh Laravel install.

Comment: username & password is valid because getting one mail in this account and remaing one goes to different account.dono what ths pblm

Comment: How do you know the other one is delivered to another mailtrap account? Do you have 2 mailtrap accounts?

Comment: yes... one for testing and other for staging

Comment: Laravel can only use one mail configuration at a time. There can be only one mail configuration in the .env, and that's the one laravel uses. If you're getting mail in your other mailtrap account, it's coming from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

```
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan view:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan clear-compiled
    php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: not wrking... still mail is sent in some  other account which i not specified in my project...